# Calculating and storing future time and dates in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I need to offer my users a way to select 11am and 4pm time slots for several days (including today) in the future, with a total of 8 options.  Of course, if it's already past 11am or 4pm today, then I shouldn't show them expired options.

So, for example, if it's currently noon on the 28th of February, then I would need to show the user the following 8 options:

```
28-Feb-13 at 4pm 
01-Mar-13 at 11am 
01-Mar-13 at 4pm 
02-Mar-13 at 11am 
02-Mar-13 at 4pm 
03-Mar-13 at 11am 
03-Mar-13 at 4pm 
04-Mar-13 at 11am
```

Also, I would need a way to store those options in MySQL so that I would now which date/time they selected and save it to the DB together with their registration info.

This sounds easy to explain in words, but I'm having an incredibly difficult time figuring out how to program this in PHP.

How would I do this using the `DateTime()` class?

Comment: check current time and write the conditions..ie, if current time < 11 am or current time < 4 pm then do the following things

Comment: @User: How do I check if it's < 11 am or < 4 pm?  How so I show tomorrow's 11 am and 4 pm times, and the following days?  How do I store the selected time in MySQL?

Comment: are weekends considered? Holidays?

Comment: use datetime class and its functions in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$hours = array(11,16);
$outputCount = 8;

$now = new DateTime();
$t = clone $now;

$dates = array();
$i=0;

while (count($dates)<$outputCount) {
    $t->setTime($hours[++$i % count($hours)],0,0);
    if ($t>$now) {
        $dates[] = clone $t;
    }
    if ($t->format('G') == max($hours)) {
        $t->modify('+1 day');
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```

Comment: Very interesting and concise solution, thanks!  A few questions: **1)** How can I set this code to work on a specific timezone? **2)** What if instead of 4pm, I needed 4:30pm, how would I do that? **3)** How should I save these time/dates in MySQL with the correct timezone?

Comment: You can set a timezone in the php.ini file or override it on the $now object at the beginning. You'd have to create a $minutes array the same size as the $hours array which you pull data out of with $i. MySQL won't record the timezone, just a time. If you want different users to see the dates in different timezones you'll have to handle that on the frontend and standardise the storage of all backend data in a single timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and I would store in DB as DATETIME:
It is up to you to optimize based on your needs, it should give you basic idea of logic:

```
<?php
    $end_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+4, date("Y"));
    $cnt = 0;
    $day = 0;

    $current_hour = date("H");
    // To test with various values, uncomment below line and assign any hour
    // $current_hour = "12";


    if($current_hour < 11)
    {
        $day = 0;
        $ts =  mktime(11, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
        echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$ts);
        $ts =  mktime(16, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
        echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$ts);
        $cnt = 2;
        $day = $day + 1;
    }
    elseif($current_hour < 16)
    {
        $day = 0;
        $ts =  mktime(16, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+$day, date("Y"));
        echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$ts);
        $cnt = 1;
        $day = $day + 1;
    }
    elseif($current_hour >= 16)
    {

        $day = $day + 1;
    }


    while($cnt <= 8)
    {
        $ts =  mktime(11, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+$day, date("Y"));
        echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$ts);
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
        if($cnt >=8) break;

        $ts =  mktime(16, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+$day, date("Y"));
        echo "<br>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$ts);    
        $cnt = $cnt + 1;
        $day = $day + 1;
        if($cnt >=8) break;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a dateTime of "now", then check if you are before 11am or not, then decide to move your hour to 11am or 4pm, and then increase to retrieve your 8 values.

Here is a piece of code that could handle this stuff:

```
// create a "now" date time
$now = new DateTime();

// create a "now at 11am" date time
$nowAt11am = new DateTime();
$nowAt11am->setTime(11, 0, 0);

// Compare the interval between now and now at 11am
$interval = $now->diff($nowAt11am);

// Initialize the increment even/odd
$incementEvenOdd = 0;

// Check interval
if ($interval->invert == 1)
{
    // $interval < 0 => we are before $nowAt11am, set to 11 am
    $now = $nowAt11am;
    $incementEvenOdd = 0;
}
else
{
    // $interval > 0 => we are after $nowAt11am, set to 4 pm
    $now->setTime(16, 0, 0);
    $incementEvenOdd = 1;
}

$dayAndHours = array();
$dayAndHours[] = $now->format("your_desire_format");

// Loop and add the next 7 dates
for($i = 0 ; $i < 7 ; $i++)
{
    // Handle the delay between 11 am and 4 pm
    // 11am -> 4pm = + 5h
    // 4pm -> 11am = + 19h

    if ($incementEvenOdd % 2 == 0)
        $now->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('5 hours'));
    else
        $now->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('19 hours'));

    // Appen the next value
    $dayAndHours[] = $now->format("your_desire_format");

    // Update increment
    $incrementEvenOdd++;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.  There's a typo in your code with the variable "incementEvenOdd" and "incRementEvenOdd", but other than that, it works!  A few questions: **1)** How can I set this code to work on a **specific timezone**?  **2)** What if instead of 5 hours, I need to add **5 and a half hours** to make the afternoon time **4:30pm**, how would I do that?  **3)** How should I save these time/dates in MySQL?

Comment: 1) Take a look at the DateTime class : http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php. You have a timezone that you can give on the constructor. 2) Take a look at the list of available format for `DateInterval::createFromDateString` here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php. I think you can use `DateInterval::createFromDateString('5 hours 30 minutes')`. 3) After creating all "dates", you can then insert them with SQL request. 4) Vote up or mark as solution if its good for U ;)